# How to use a 'subroutine reference' as a hash key

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine, dereference

In Perl, I'm learning how to dereference 'subroutine references'. But I can't seem to use a subroutine reference as a hash 'key'.

In the following sample code,

1. I can create a reference to a subroutine ($subref) and then dereference it to run the subroutine (&$subref)
2. I can use the reference as a hash 'value' and then easily dereference that
3. But I cannot figure out how to use the reference as a hash 'key'. When I pull the key out of the hash, Perl interprets the key as a string value (not a reference) - which I now [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084482/1306717) (thanks to this site!). So I've tried Hash::MultiKey, but that seems to turn it into an array reference. I want to treat it as a subroutine/code reference, assuming this is somehow possible?

Any other ideas?

```
use strict;
#use diagnostics;
use Hash::MultiKey;    

my $subref = \&hello;

#1: 
&$subref('bob','sue');               #okay

#2:
my %hash;
$hash{'sayhi'}=$subref;
&{$hash{'sayhi'}}('bob','sue');      #okay

#3: 
my %hash2;
tie %hash2, 'Hash::MultiKey';
$hash2{$subref}=1;
foreach my $key (keys %hash2) {
  print "Ref type is: ". ref($key)."\n";
  &{$key}('bob','sue');              # Not okay 
}

sub hello {
    my $name=shift;
    my $name2=shift;
    print "hello $name and $name2\n";
}
```

This is what is returned:

```
hello bob and sue
hello bob and sue
Ref type is: ARRAY
Not a CODE reference at d:\temp\test.pl line 21.
```

Comment: But why are you trying to use a coderef as a hash key in the first place? Use something else as an index and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I think the question is valid somehow: How does the Perl debugger detect "REUSED_ADDRESS" in an array of CODE references? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, a normal hash key is only a string. Things that are not strings get coerced to their string representation.

```
my $coderef = sub { my ($name, $name2) = @_; say "hello $name and $name2"; };
my %hash2 = ( $coderef => 1, );
print keys %hash2;  # 'CODE(0x8d2280)'
```

[Tie](http://p3rl.org/perltie)ing is the usual means to modify that behaviour, but [Hash::MultiKey](http://p3rl.org/Hash%3a%3aMultiKey) does not help you, it has a different purpose: as the name says, you may have multiple keys, but again only simple strings:

```
use Hash::MultiKey qw();
tie my %hash2, 'Hash::MultiKey';
$hash2{ [$coderef] } = 1;
foreach my $key (keys %hash2) {
    say 'Ref of the key is: ' . ref($key);
    say 'Ref of the list elements produced by array-dereferencing the key are:';
    say ref($_) for @{ $key }; # no output, i.e. simple strings
    say 'List elements produced by array-dereferencing the key are:';
    say $_ for @{ $key }; # 'CODE(0x8d27f0)'
}
```

Instead, use [Tie::RefHash](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aRefHash). (Code critique: prefer this syntax with the `->` arrow for dereferencing a coderef.)

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Tie::RefHash qw();

my $coderef = sub {
    my ($name, $name2) = @_;
    say "hello $name and $name2";
};

$coderef->(qw(bob sue));

my %hash = (sayhi => $coderef);
$hash{sayhi}->(qw(bob sue));

tie my %hash2, 'Tie::RefHash';
%hash2 = ($coderef => 1);
foreach my $key (keys %hash2) {
    say 'Ref of the key is: ' . ref($key);   # 'CODE'
    $key->(qw(bob sue));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html):

> [How can I use a reference as a hash key?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-use-a-reference-as-a-hash-key%3f)
>
> (contributed by brian d foy and Ben Morrow)
>
> Hash keys are strings, so you can't really use a reference as the key.
>   When you try to do that, perl turns the reference into its stringified
>   form (for instance, HASH(0xDEADBEEF) ). From there you can't get back
>   the reference from the stringified form, at least without doing some
>   extra work on your own.
>
> Remember that the entry in the hash will still be there even if the
>   referenced variable goes out of scope, and that it is entirely
>   possible for Perl to subsequently allocate a different variable at the
>   same address. This will mean a new variable might accidentally be
>   associated with the value for an old.
>
> If you have Perl 5.10 or later, and you just want to store a value
>   against the reference for lookup later, you can use the core
>   Hash::Util::Fieldhash module. This will also handle renaming the keys
>   if you use multiple threads (which causes all variables to be
>   reallocated at new addresses, changing their stringification), and
>   garbage-collecting the entries when the referenced variable goes out
>   of scope.
>
> If you actually need to be able to get a real reference back from each
>   hash entry, you can use the Tie::RefHash module, which does the
>   required work for you.

So it looks like [Tie::RefHash](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aRefHash) will do what you want. But to be honest, I don't think that what you want to do is a particularly good idea.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. The danger is that I may inadvertently clobber variables (e.g., if they are referenced out of scope)? To help me understand, are you able to illustrate this potential danger by expanding on daxim's code sample? Perhaps by adding a "dangerous scope" scenario? I believe, for example that qw(bob sue) could be clobbered by say, qw(fred barney)? Or perhaps I have misunderstood. Thank you greatly for your tutelage!

Comment: I said "I don't think that what you want to do is a particularly good idea" not because it's dangerous, but because there's almost certainly a better way to do what you want to do. Trying to use hash keys as references is bizarre. It's not what they're for. Hash keys are just strings that identify hash values. It's like saying that you want array indexes to be real numbers.

Comment: Point taken. There are many ways to do what I need. I merely thought this was an interesting route: 'process as index'. While bizarre, I find it intriguing. Thanks again to this community for your thoughtful responses!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it? If you e.g. need to store parameters to the functions in the hash, you can use HoH:

```
my %hash;
$hash{$subref} = { sub => $subref,
                   arg => [qw/bob sue/],
                 };
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    print "$key: ref type is: " . ref($key) . "\n";
    $hash{$key}{sub}->( @{ $hash{$key}{arg} } );
}
```

But then, you can probably choose a better key anyway.