# Pairs as hash keys

Tags: perl, list, hash

Does anyone know how to make a hash with pairs of strings serving as keys in perl?

Something like...

```
{
    ($key1, $key2) => $value1;
    ($key1, $key3) => $value2;
    ($key2, $key3) => $value3;
```

etc....

Comment: Related: [Hash::MultiKey](http://p3rl.org/Hash::MultiKey) [Tie::RefHash](http://p3rl.org/Tie::RefHash) [Can Perl store an array reference as a hash key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083433/can-perl-store-an-array-reference-as-a-hash-key) [How to use a 'subroutine reference' as a hash key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795386/how-to-use-a-subroutine-reference-as-a-hash-key)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have a pair of scalars as a hash key, but you can make a multilevel hash:

```
my %hash;
$hash{$key1}{$key2} = $value1;
$hash{$key1}{$key3} = $value2;
$hash{$key2}{$key3} = $value3;
```

If you want to define it all at once:

```
my %hash = ( $key1 => { $key2 => $value1, $key3 => $value2 },
             $key2 => { $key3 => $value3 } );
```

Alternatively, if it works for your situation, you could just concatenate your keys together

```
$hash{$key1 . $key2} = $value1;   # etc
```

Or add a delimiter to separate the keys:

```
$hash{"$key1:$key2"} = $value1;   # etc
```

Comment: your first suggestion is great, as for the second, its best to have a separator to prevent collisions like 123 456 and 12 3456...

Comment: There are ASCII characters defined for just this purpose; the Unit Separator (hex 1f) is probably the most suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [invisible separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Mathematical_invisibles) to join the coordinates:

> Primarily for mathematics, the Invisible Separator (`U+2063`) provides a separator between characters where punctuation or space may be omitted such as in a two-dimensional index like `i⁣j`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use charnames qw(:full :short);

use YAML;

my %sparse_matrix = (
    mk_key(34,56) => -1,
    mk_key(1200,11) => 1,
);

print Dump \%sparse_matrix;

sub mk_key { join("\N{INVISIBLE SEPARATOR}", @_) }

sub mk_vec { map [split "\N{INVISIBLE SEPARATOR}"], @_ }
```

```
~/tmp> perl mm.pl |xxd
0000000: 2d2d 2d0a 3132 3030 e281 a331 313a 2031  ---.1200...11: 1
0000010: 0a33 34e2 81a3 3536 3a20 2d31 0a         .34...56: -1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
{ "$key1\x1F$key2" => $value, ... }
```

Usually with a helper method:

```
sub getKey() {
    return join( "\x1F", @_ );
}

{ getKey( $key1, $key2 ) => $value, ... }
```

**----- EDIT -----**

Updated the code above to use the ASCII Unit Separator per the [recommendation from @chepner above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297279/pairs-as-hash-keys/15297310#comment21590632_15297343)

Comment: Or you can set $; to "\x1F" and use $hash{$key1,$key2} = $value or { "$key1$;$key2" => $value}

Comment: @MkV, gotta love perl...  soooooo many ways to do everything :)

Answer (score 1):

*Usage*: Multiple *keys* of a *single value* in a hash can be used for implementing a *2D matrix* or *N-dimensional matrix*!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();

my ($a, $b, $c) = (2,3,4);
$hash{"$a, $b ,$c"} = 1;
$hash{"$b, $c ,$a"} = 1;

foreach(keys(%hash) )
{
    my @a = split(/,/, $_);
    print Dumper(@a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [$;](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24SUBSCRIPT_SEPARATOR) implicitly (or explicitly) in your hash keys, used for multidimensional emulation, like so:

```
my %hash;
$hash{$key1, $key2} = $value; # or %hash = ( $key1.$;.$key2 => $value );
print $hash{$key1, $key2} # returns $value
```

You can even set $; to \x1F if needed (the default is \034, from SUBSEP in awk):

```
local $; = "\x1F";
```